# String decode extracted from web log

Tags: security, urldecode

Working on log analysis, I found a string with odd syntax and contents, by  parsing page field of web log (a webshell?):

```
/campaign/(f(2ewt_ygmarlagti7sw4tvhj0zk17klgxnhnk1aawgtixm5x-2qmvsvouolvaffrhitumf4wnk496p2dbzmkc3ywfloksiixdtrlawmt78f_mg-45kdzzpdlnogeishkcgtohttp://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.phptelf6gqmu2ia0i1j5lfgmcvw1))/home/index
```

Could someone guide me how to decode this string and find a clue ? Also why is the following:

```
http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php
```

included in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quoting https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php

> Facebook allows its users to send links to interesting web content to other Facebook users. Part of how this works on the Facebook system involves the temporary display of certain images or details related to the web content, such as the title of the web page or the embed tag of a video. Our system retrieves this information only after a user provides us with a link. You may have found this page because a Facebook user sent a link from your website to other Facebook users. If you have any questions or concerns about any links or content sent by one of our users, please contact us at legal@facebook.com.

My guess is that someone posted a link to your website to Facebook and someone clicked on that link (visited your website through that link). The (probably) encoded stuff seem a bit random though. If I were you I would either post a link from my website on Facebook, click on it and see if I get something similar. If it doesn't look like that, I would contact legal@facebook.com to clarify whether it is linked to them.